# scss rendering error [Internal Error: File to read not found or unreadable:]

Tags: css, sass

I want to make a website with scss but when i save the scss file it gives me an error. However, if I saved it a couple times then it will render completely.
Its nothing major but it bugs me.

I tried finding an answer in Google but nothing works

This is just a simple scss file because I am just trying to check if there's an error before i begin my project. turns out there is.

```
@import "fixed";

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #444;
}
```

```
{
  "status": 3,
  "message": "File to read not found or unreadable: E:/Coding Stuff/Websites/bs4/scss/main.scss",
  "formatted": "Internal Error: File to read not found or unreadable: E:/Coding Stuff/Websites/bs4/scss/main.scss\n"
}
```

after saving a few times then:

```
=> changed: E:\Coding Stuff\Websites\bs4\scss\main.scss
Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
Wrote CSS to E:\Coding Stuff\Websites\bs4\css\main.css
```

What did i do wrong?
please help

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using npm..

Comment: Is your text editor Sublime Text by any chance? I know the atomic saves option can cause this kind of problem.

Comment: nope, its VS code. I'm guessing there's something wrong the node_modules dependencies

Comment: Found [this page](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1894) which might be related to your problem

Comment: Most solutions on the link I gave previously seems to consist in modifying the render.js file. Either by setting a small Timeout on `sass.render()` to allow VSCode to finish,  or a "retry" in case of a `isFileUnreadable(error)`. Did you try those solutions ?

Answer (score 3):

Follow below steps

1. > npm i sass --save
2. Add to package.json: `"scripts": { "sass": "sass --watch sass/style.scss:css/style.css" }`
3. Add 2 folders `(sass & css)` and add a file in sass `(style.scss)`
4. Type in terminal > `npm run sass`

Answer (score 2):

if you are using a node-sass as the compiler and vscode or sublime text AFAIK, the issue is with atomic save option where node-sass can't have access to transpile the scss file because the editor is still busy with it. Two ways of fixing this include:

1. Replace render.js file of `node-sass`

check [here](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1894#issuecomment-390199128)
there is a drawback of having to do this everytime you install node-sass

2. Install `sass` module instead

   $ yarn add -D sass
   script

   $ sass --watch input.scss output.css